# How to Disable Exoplayer Video Layout

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I want to use only controls of exoplayer I don't need video  preview black screen, my use case is audio.
I use custom control layout but it doesn't make and difference.[exoplayer with blackScreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uu6tt.jpg). I couldn't find anything related to black screen on default control view in default control view file of exoplayer.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
        android:id="@+id/playerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:fastforward_increment="5000"
        app:rewind_increment="5000"
        app:show_timeout="0"
        app:hide_on_touch="false"
        app:use_artwork="false"
        app:use_controller="true"
        app:controller_layout_id="@layout/custom_exo_controller_view"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**custom_exo_controller_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Copyright (C) 2016 The Android Open Source Project
     Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     You may obtain a copy of the License at
          http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
     Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     limitations under the License.
-->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layoutDirection="ltr"
    android:background="@color/purple_200"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:targetApi="28">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_rew"
            style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Rewind"/>



        <ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_play"
            style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Play"/>

        <ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_pause"
            style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Pause"/>
        <ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_prev"
            style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Previous"
           />

        <ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_ffwd"
            style="@style/ExoMediaButton.FastForward"/>



    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView android:id="@id/exo_position"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp"
            android:paddingRight="4dp"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:textColor="#FFBEBEBE"/>


        <TextView android:id="@id/exo_duration"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp"
            android:paddingRight="4dp"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:textColor="#FFBEBEBE"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if your use case is audio so why exoplayer?

Comment: simple, it's easier to use

Comment: https://steemit.com/utopian-io/@steemibal/create-a-simple-audio-player-in-android-by-exoplayer

Comment: https://www.codexpedia.com/android/android-playing-audio-with-exoplayer-2-example/